# Error: rxjs/operator/map has no exported member 'map'

Tags: angular6, rxjs6

I'm migrating from angular 5 to angular 6. When I make npm run build, I'm it is throw to the console the following error:

> error TS2305: Module
>   '"C:/PrjNET/Elevation3/FW/4.00/Mainline/Framework/Development/Client/ElevationJS/ngcore/.tmp/node_modules/rxjs/operator/map"'
>   has no exported member 'map'.

I'm importing `map` as follows:

```
import { map} from 'rxjs/operator/map';
```

Any one knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It is just need to change the import from this:

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operator/map';
```

to this:

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
```